# scrollTop() different in firefox vs chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I would like to have the entire scrollable height of the window. However while chrome returns the length of the part visible to the user without scrolling, firefox returns the entire scrollable length. 
how can I fix this inconsistancy without have to detect the browser first.
At the moment I am using

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

Comment: You want the `height` of the `document`? What re you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).scrollTop()` works the same in both, it tells you how far down you have scrolled.

`$(window).height()` gives the height of the viewport.

`$(document).height()` gives the height of the document which I think you are looking for.

Or, if you are looking for only the scroll height outside of the viewport, then

`$(document).height() - $(window).height()`